# How much HP does "Ygdar Orus Li Ox" revive you with?

Tags: dead-cells

The "Ygdar Orus Li Ox" mutation "saves you one time if you die prematurely while not cursed". Do you stay at 1hp when you get saved, or do you get a bit of extra HP so you don't die immediately after if you get hit again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Upon taking lethal damage which does not trigger sudden death prevention, it freezes nearby enemies, **restores 25% of the player's max health**, removes all accumulated Malaise and then becomes disabled for the rest of the run.

Source, [Dead Cells wiki](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Ygdar_Orus_Li_Ox).